# Unable to unlocalize a Component because a Publish Transaction is in process

Tags: publishing, 2009, localization

We have a Page `navigation.xml` and it is associated with a Component which has been localized.

Now, when we try to unlocalize that Component, it gives the error: "Publish Transaction is in process, can not be unlocalized".

I have checked the Transaction folder, which is empty and also the Page/Component is showing a failed status in the queue. Still the error says Transaction is in process. I have checked the database (CM), where the status is marked as: 5.

Could you please tell how to overcome this situation so that the Component can be unlocalized?

Tridion version: 2009

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried removing the component from the page, then unlocalizing it, then re-adding it to the page?

Comment: I have tried as suggested, but problem persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to assume that the message is not a mistake, as this logic is quite solid. You *probably* have an old transaction that is still pending. Make sure you set filters in the publishing queue allowing you to see:

- Transactions by any user instead of current one
- Transactions of any date instead of the current date

By default the publishing queue will only show transactions started by the current user today.